React rendering infinitely
I have this React component that whenever I change the dates and click on the Filter Data button the useTransactionLog runs infinitely. When I click the page it is working fine but only when changing the Date Picker values and clicking Filter Data.
I added a log in the useTransactionLog hook and it keeps on showing after clicking the button and the UI just freezes. I think something is re-rendering the hook but am not sure what it is.
This is the component code:
import { useState, useMemo } from 'react'
import Table from '@/components/ui/Table'
import Pagination from '@/components/ui/Pagination'
import Select from '@/components/ui/Select'
import {
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  flexRender,
} from '@tanstack/react-table'
import type { ColumnDef } from '@tanstack/react-table'
import { Badge, Button, DatePicker } from '@/components/ui'
import { HiOutlineDownload, HiOutlineFilter } from 'react-icons/hi'
import { useTransactionLog } from '../mtAccounts/useTransactionLog'
import { TransactionLogView } from '@/@types/mtAccounts'
import { Loading } from '@/components/shared'
import { useAppSelector } from '@/store'
import AccessDenied from '@/pages/AccessDenied'

type Option = {
  value: number
  label: string
}

const { Tr, Th, Td, THead, TBody } = Table

const pageSizeOption = [
  { value: 10, label: '10 / page' },
  { value: 20, label: '20 / page' },
  { value: 30, label: '30 / page' },
  { value: 40, label: '40 / page' },
  { value: 50, label: '50 / page' },
]

const TransactionsLog = () => {
  const currentDate = new Date()
  const yesterday = new Date(currentDate)
  yesterday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1) // Set to yesterday

  const nextDay = new Date(currentDate)
  nextDay.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1) // Set to next day
  const [tempFrom, setTempFrom] = useState(yesterday)
  const [tempTo, setTempTo] = useState(nextDay)
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    startDate: tempFrom.toLocaleDateString(),
    endDate: tempTo.toLocaleDateString(),
  })

  const columns = useMemo<ColumnDef<TransactionLogView>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        header: 'Email',
        accessorKey: 'email',
      },
      {
        header: 'Type',
        accessorKey: 'type',
        cell: (props) => {
          const { type } = props.row.original
          return (
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <Badge
                className={`${
                  type === 'IN'
                    ? 'bg-emerald-500'
                    : 'bg-red-500'
                }`}
              />
              <span
                className={`ml-2 rtl:mr-2 capitalize font-semibold ${
                  type === 'IN'
                    ? 'text-emerald-500'
                    : 'text-red-500'
                }`}
              >
                {type}
              </span>
            </div>
          )
        },
      },
      {
        header: 'Account',
        accessorKey: 'account',
      },
      {
        header: 'Amount',
        accessorKey: 'amount',
      },
      {
        header: 'Currency',
        accessorKey: 'currency',
      },
      {
        header: 'Date',
        accessorKey: 'date',
      },
      {
        header: 'Comment',
        accessorKey: 'comment',
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  const { isLoading, trx: data } = useTransactionLog(dateRange)

  const totalData = data?.length
  const table = useReactTable({
    data: data || [],
    columns,
    // Pipeline
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
  })

  const onPaginationChange = (page: number) => {
    table.setPageIndex(page - 1)
  }

  const onSelectChange = (value = 0) => {
    table.setPageSize(Number(value))
  }

  const handleCalenderFrom = (date: Date | null) => {
    console.log(date)
    if (date != null) setTempFrom(date)
  }

  const handleCalenderTo = (date: Date | null) => {
    if (date) setTempTo(date as Date)
  }

  const handleFilterData = () => {
    console.log(dateRange)
    if (
      tempFrom.toLocaleDateString() !== dateRange.startDate ||
      tempTo.toLocaleDateString() !== dateRange.endDate
    ) {
      setDateRange({
        startDate: tempFrom.toLocaleDateString(),
        endDate: tempTo.toLocaleDateString(),
      })
    }
    console.log(dateRange)
  }

  const { role } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.user)

  return (
    <div>
      <Loading loading={isLoading}>
        <div className="lg:flex items-center justify-between mb-4">
          <h3 className="mb-4 lg:mb-0">Transactions</h3>

          <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:items-center gap-4">
            <DatePicker
              value={tempFrom}
              onChange={handleCalenderFrom}
            />
            <DatePicker
              value={tempTo}
              onChange={handleCalenderTo}
            />
            <Button
              variant="solid"
              icon={<HiOutlineFilter />}
              onClick={handleFilterData}
            >
              Filter Data
            </Button>
            <Button icon={<HiOutlineDownload />}>
              Export
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Table>
          <THead>
            {table.getHeaderGroups()
              .map((headerGroup) => (
                <Tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                  {headerGroup.headers
                    .map((header) => {
                      return (
                        <Th
                          key={header.id}
                          colSpan={header.colSpan}
                        >
                          {flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                        </Th>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </Tr>
              ))
            }
          </THead>
          <TBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {
              return (
                <Tr key={row.id}>
                  {row.getVisibleCells()
                    .map((cell) => {
                      return (
                        <Td key={cell.id}>
                          {flexRender(
                            cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                            cell.getContext()
                          )}
                        </Td>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </Tr>
              )
            })}
          </TBody>
        </Table>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-4">
          <Pagination
            pageSize={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
            currentPage={table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1}
            total={totalData}
            onChange={onPaginationChange}
          />
          <div style={{ minWidth: 130 }}>
            <Select<Option>
              size="sm"
              isSearchable={false}
              value={pageSizeOption.filter(
                (option) =>
                  option.value === table.getState().pagination.pageSize
                )
              }
              options={pageSizeOption}
              onChange={(option) => onSelectChange(option?.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Loading>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TransactionsLog

TransactionLog hook Code:
export function useTransactionLog({
  startDate,
  endDate,
}: {
  startDate: string
  endDate: string
}) {
  console.log(startDate, endDate)
  const { isLoading, data: trx } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['transactionlog', startDate, endDate],
    queryFn: () => getTransactionLog(startDate, endDate),
  })
  return { isLoading, trx }
}


You need to strip this down to a minimal reproduction case, ideally with a link to a code sandbox. It's not very likely that people are going to want to wade through 100+ LoC.

one way to find out what's causing rerenders would be adding useEffect(() => console.log('"state" changed:', state), [state]) for different states your component is using. If one of them spams the console, you know. :)

Thanks. But nothing is actually spamming the console, only the useTransactionLog hook when i change the dateRange value it get executed infinite times
